# Am I missing something, or does "qmlRegisterSingletonInstance" have a bug?

Tags: qt, qml

We are getting an apparently false error message when we create a singleton instance using the new "qmlRegisterSingletonInstance" function. We create the instance like this in main.cpp:

```
QScopedPointer<OSClog> OSClog(new class OSClog);
qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("Louma.osclog", 1, 0, "OSClog", OSClog.get() );
```

But in our QML file, we get this error message on import, claiming the module can't be found:
[image]

But it CAN be found, and the program compiles and runs correctly.

If we use a different function to create that type, the error message disappears. Using this code instead does not report the error:

`qmlRegisterType<OSClog>("Louma.osclog", 1, 0, "OSClog" );`

Although we now need to create an instance of the component in main.qml.

We've been putting up with the error message for months, as it was just a minor annoyance until now. We have just discovered that Qt-Designer refuses to load any object that includes that import statement.

[image]

Of course, this error is also phony, as the QML_IMPORT_PATH is correct. If we change the code away from "qmlRegisterSingletonInstance" to any of the other registration function, Qt-Designer works correctly.

So, are we doing something wrong with "qmlRegisterSingletonInstance"? Or is this a bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be instantiating and using it correctly. As you say it builds and runs just fine so it obviously is a bug in Qt Creator IDE.

Yes, you can find an unresolved creator bug [Add support for qmlRegisterSingletonInstance](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23629) from Qt bug tracker. And also [qmlRegisterSingletonInstance is not detected by Qt Creator](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23945) which has been duplicated to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks, Talamaki.  We tried to search for a bug report, but a search for "qmlRegisterSingletonInstance" kept coming up empty. It seems that the bug was reported, but not acknowledged by the Qt people. Hence, there doesn't seem to be a work-around.